# Move element XML not working (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, category, layout, xml

I am editing my theme `default.xml` in a child theme I have created. Which sits in `mytheme\Magento_Catalog\layout\default.xml` This file works fine as parts of what I have done does work. Basically what I have done is created a new container `category.header` and then thrown `category.image` and `page.main.title` in it. This works as I can see the items in the new container in my category pages.

The bit that doesn't work that is driving me mad is moving the new container, `category.header`. Moving the element just doesn't seem to have an affect. All I want to do is move it below the nav and above the main content. Can anyone spot why?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <container name="compare-link-wrapper" label="Compare Link Wrapper" as="compare-link-wrapper" after="top.search" htmlTag="ul" htmlClass="compare wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.compare.link" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/link.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="compareProducts" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/compare-products</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
          <container name="category.header" as="categoryHeader" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-header" before="page.main" />
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="category.image" destination="category.header" />
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="category.header" />

        <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="columns.top" after="category.image" />

        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't reference the page.wrapper container and create category.header inside:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="category.header" as="categoryHeader" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-header" before="main.content" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried that. It works but, changing the order it appears on the page with before="page.main" doesn't seem to work. I can't work out why. Have updated the code in my original question.

Comment: Ok, I have worked this out. I should have been using before="main.content" and not before="page.main" Mystery solved :)

Comment: That's great. I've changed my answer so others can see how it should be.